# Android Resource File for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, layout

I am using Android Studio 2.3.2 and is in the midst of creating an Android Application. I have a content_main.xml and an activity_main.xml set up and designed. Now that I want it to support different screen sizes, I understand that I have to create a new xml layout for the appropriate sizes??

Like if I want it to support small, medium, large and x-large I need to duplicate that layout 4 times??

Do I copy from content_main.xml or activity.main.xml to adjust the layouts??

Sorry, I am just confused about it as I am new, any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: I think you don't need to create 4 layout. You can create that but creating 4 different dimen resource file can help you to achieve what you require. But you can create different layout for tablets which in fact can have different layout.

Comment: Create a nice responsive design which will work on all devices , rather then creating 4 different layouts . It'll take some time but its good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
[image]

you can create different screen with respect to ratio/UI Mode etc

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer!

Comment: But which one to use? content_main.xml or activity_main.xml??

Comment: @Justin : its upto your logic to use xml file, some xml files dont need different screen

Answer (score 0):

Just click on (Layout Variants) icon next to (AppTheme - Languages )

then choose which size you want .. and let the magic happen